# How to stream raw data from web audio into webrtc data channel

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

I use `getUserMedia` to the the audio stream, and pass the stream into web audio using `createMediaStreamSource`. I then want to stream the raw audio data into a webrtc data channel.

There isn’t a data channel destination node in web audio. I’ve only been able to access the raw audio data from inside an audio worklet, but I don’t know how to get that data into a data channel. How should I go about streaming raw audio from `getUserMedia` data into a data channel?

Comment: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/webrtc-integration.html  you could review this  &  https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-a-client-side-web-app-which-streams-audio-from-a-browser-microphone-to-a-server-part-ii-df20ddb47d4e